# Convert HTML tag to lowercase

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-6, uppercase, lowercase

I working on an intranet project for IE6 (i know...) and I need to output some HTML code from a div.

I use `$('#output').text($('#container').html());`

But IE6 outputs all the code in uppercase:

```
<TABLE border=1>
 <TR>
  <TD>Test Content</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

How can I convert HTML tags to lowercase using jQuery?

Would be useful to have a plugin that could recursively go trough the DOM-tree.

Comment: Allright, you say you know about that IE6 sucks ... then why tables? ;)

Comment: Tables are still valid for tabular data.  
You're not supposed to ban the use of them altogether, just use them in their intended context.

Comment: David is correct, it's for tabular data. GaVrA: I have a big table with information that is just static HTML code from an article from an awful CMS. So a user can edit it using jEditable and then get the code and add into the article again. Pretty clever and awful, I know :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$('#output').text($('#container').html().replace(/<\/?[A-Z]+.*?>/g, function (m) { return m.toLowerCase(); }));
```

Comment: almost, doesn't support attributes though. can you fix that?

Comment: I changed it to support attributes, but it is also change attributes to lowercase, is that what you want?

Answer (score -2):

What if you use .html() instead of .text()?

Comment: I assume the OP wants to display the HTML so it can be copy/pasted. If it was being treated as markup, it wouldn't matter that IE used upper case tag and attribute names internally.