# Using jquery or JS how do you turn a string into a link?

Tags: jquery, dynamic-links

So I have a piece of HTML that looks something like this...

```
<p>This is some copy. In this copy is the word hello</p>
```

I want to turn the word hello into a link using jquery.

```
<p>This is some copy. In this copy is the word <a href="">hello</a></p>
```

That in itself is not too hard. My problem is that if the word is already apart of a link like the example below...

```
<p>In this copy is the <a href="">word hello</a></p>
```

I don't want that to end up with a link within a link...

```
<p>In this copy is the <a href="">word <a href="">hello</a></a></p>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you not just call parent("a") on the text element and see if does not return null?

Comment: Can you post the code you're already using?

Answer (score 3):

A little regex should do the trick (Update, see below):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var needle = 'hello';
    $('p').each(function(){
        var me = $(this),
            txt = me.html(),
            found = me.find(needle).length;
        if (found != -1) {
            txt = txt.replace(/(hello)(?!.*?<\/a>)/gi, '<a href="">$1</a>');
            me.html(txt);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G8rKw/

**Edit: This version works better:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var needle = 'hello';
    $('p').each(function() {
        var me = $(this),
            txt = me.html(),
            found = me.find(needle).length;
        if (found != -1) {
            txt = txt.replace(/(hello)(?![^(<a.*?>).]*?<\/a>)/gi, '<a href="">$1</a>');
            me.html(txt);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G8rKw/3/

**Edit again: This time, "hello" is passed as a variable to the regex**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var needle = 'hello';
    $('p').each(function() {
        var me = $(this),
        txt = me.html(),
        found = me.find(needle).length,
        regex = new RegExp('(' + needle + ')(?![^(<a.*?>).]*?<\/a>)','gi');
        if (found != -1) {
            txt = txt.replace(regex, '<a href="">$1</a>');
            me.html(txt);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webrocker/MtM3s/

Comment: hm, the regex needs more refinement; if there is 'hello' in front of '<a href="">word hello</a>', it will not be replaced, since _/(hello)(?!.*?<\/a>)_ will look for "hello" not followed by a closing </a> tag -- somehow an opening <a> tag must also be included in this expression to stop the match…

Comment: Added a 2nd version that works with the combinations of originally lined and linkless searchterms in one paragraph.

Comment: Added 3rd version, where "hello" is passed as a variable in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HfZLk/3/)**

```
$('p').each(function(){    
    if($(this).find('a').length > 0) return;  
    lastSpaceIndex = $(this).text().lastIndexOf(' ');
    if(lastSpaceIndex  == -1)
        lastSpaceIndex = 0;    
    WordToReplace = $(this).text().substring(lastSpaceIndex);
    idx = $(this).text().lastIndexOf(WordToReplace);
    resultstring = $(this).text().substring(0, idx); 
    $(this).html(resultstring);
    $(this).append($( "<a href='#'>" + WordToReplace  + "</a>"));
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery solution searches for a particular term and doesn't create a link if it finds it's followed by a closing link tag.

```
var searchTerm = "hello";

$('p:contains("' + searchTerm + '")').each(function(){
    var searchString = $(this).html();
    var searchIndex = searchString.indexOf(searchTerm);
    var startString = searchString.substr(0 , searchIndex);
    var endString = searchString.substr(searchIndex + searchTerm.length);
    if(endString.match(/<\/a>/g)) return;
    $(this).html(startString + "<a href=''>" + searchTerm + "</a>" + endString);
});​
```

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/YV6ZD/) to a jsfiddle for it.

Comment: Close but fails when you enclose with another word like `<p>This is some copy. In this copy the word <a href="">is hello</a></p>`

Comment: @Vega Changing to your example, it succeeds - because hello is followed by a closing tag, and it will return - as is desired by Paul. However, if it's `<p>This is some copy. In this copy the word <a href="">hello is</a></p>` it will fail. I've updated my solution so that it's able to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a simple function to check if the replacing text is enclosed by a link tag. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wyUYb/4/

```
function changeToLink (sel, txt) {
   var regEx = new RegExp(txt, 'g');
   $.each($(sel), function (i, el) {
       var linkHTML = $(el).html();
       var idx = linkHTML.indexOf(txt);

       if (idx >= 0) {
           var t = linkHTML.substring(idx);
           //Fix for IE returning tag names in upper case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873326/convert-html-tag-to-lowercase
           t = t.replace(/<\/?[A-Z]+.*?>/g, function (m) { return m.toLowerCase(); })
           var closingA = t.indexOf('</a>');

           t = t.substring(0, closingA);
           if (closingA != -1) {
               t = t.substring(0, closingA); 
               if (t.indexOf('<a') < txt.length) {
                   return;
               }
           }               

           linkHTML = linkHTML.replace(regEx, '<a href="">' + txt + '</a>');
           $(el).html(linkHTML);
       }           
   });
}
```

Also even if you add a nested link your browser would simply change it to two links. May be because it is not legal to use nested links. See below,

Also documented in W3C for [Nested Links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

> **12.2.2 Nested links are illegal**
>
> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.
>
> Since the DTD defines the LINK element to be empty, LINK elements may
>   not be nested either.

And that is why browser handles nested link as separate links.

http://jsfiddle.net/H44jE/

See the firebug inspect on right bottom of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you not test for the parent element of the word before turning it into a link?

```
if (parent != 'a') {
   // do your thing
}
```

(I don't know what the actual jQuery would be to test this)

**EDIT**

The following will replace the word in all `<p>` elements that DO NOT contain a link in them.

May not work exactly as required but hopefully points you in the direction

```
// get all p elements that contain the word hello but DO NOT have link in them
var elems = $('p:contains("hello")').not(':has(a)');


// replace instances of hello in the selected p elements
$(elems).html($(elems).html().replace(/(hello)/g,'<a href="new">$1</a>'));
```

[Live Demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/32609/)

Comment: That is my problem, I don't know the actual jquery either. Because you are selecting a string (the word Hello) rather than a dom element, I don't know how you check its immediate parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user .replace jquery function something like this:

```
var str = $('p').html().replace('(some)','(to some)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the jquery :not selector, or .not().

The API docs cover this well, you should be able to select your content, then deselect links within it.

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the word and trying to find its parent, search for the link and check the word it contains:

```
if($('a').text() === "hello"){
  //already linked
}else{
  //not linked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First keep the words while getting rid of the current anchor tag, if there is one:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
 });
```

Then do a replace on the string that you need to work with

```
$('p').html($('p').text().replace('hello', '<a href="">hello</a>'));
```